# integer solution of $\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3-xy(x+y)-yz(y+z)-xz(x+z)-2xyz}{(x+y+z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(x-y-z)}=\frac{1}{2016}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3-xy(x+y)-yz(y+z)-xz(x+z)-2xyz}{(x+y+z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(x-y-z)}=\frac{1}{2016}$.

How to find all solutions ?

I have no any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the variables are symmetric, one can set $x≤y≤z$ without loss of generality. Some small solutions $x,\,y,\,z$ are, $$ 4,\, 10,\, 22\\  12,\, 138,\, 210\\  21,\, 60,\, 129\\  35,\, 182,\, 343\\  35,\, 210,\, 385\\  36,\, 45,\, 135\\  42,\, 84,\, 210 \\ 70,\, 84,\, 266\\  110,\, 110,\, 396$$ Curiously, some triplets share common terms, like $84,\,210$ etc.

Comment: Are there infinite solutions ?

Comment: The fact that there are already this many solutions in the narrow search space I used may suggest that there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Since$$\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{3}-xy(x+y)-yz(y+z)-zx(z+x)-2xyz}{(x+y+z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(x-y-z)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{-x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x-y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y-z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}\right),$$
 we are trying to solve $$\frac{1}{-x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x-y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y-z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}=\frac{1}{1008}.$$
 This is equivalent to solving the equation $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a+b+c}=\frac{1}{1008}.$$

Comment: It's a beautiful simplification. But a small note: we lose the positivity requirement. For example, the smallest $x,\,y,\,z = 4,\,10,\,22$ yields $a,\,b,\,c = 28,\,16,\,\color{brown}{-8}$.

Answer (score 3):

This method uses *Pythagorean triples* $x^2+y^2=z^2$ to solve,

$$\frac{1}{-x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x-y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y-z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}=\frac{1}{N}\tag1$$

It does not give all the solutions, but does give an ***easy*** way to tackle general $N$.

Let $x\leq y\leq z$. The method is based on the fortuitous observation that some $x,y,z$ (of a higher search range) were Pythagorean triples. Substitute,

$$x,\,y,\,z = a^2-b^2,\;2ab,\;a^2+b^2$$

into $(1)$, and one gets a much simpler equation,

$$(a-b)b = N\tag2$$

Thus, quick solutions can be found using the **divisors** of $N$. For $N = 1008$, this has *thirty*, namely,

$$b = \color{brown}{1}, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 36, 42, 48, 56, 63, 72, 84, 112, 126, 144, 168, 252, 336, 504, \color{brown}{1008}.$$

For example, using $a,b = 1009,\color{brown}1$ yields,

$$x,\,y,\,z = 1018080,\; 2018,\; 1018082$$

while $a,b = 1009,\color{brown}{1008}$ gives,

$$x,\,y,\,z = 2017,\; 2034144,\; 2034145$$

and so on for thirty solutions to $(1)$ that also obey $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Comment: Thank you . Do you have a solution with $x^2+y^2\neq z^2$ ?

Comment: @Bless: None of the small solutions I listed below your original question are Pythagorean triples.